# Android - Set action for pressing enter

Tags: android

I developed a search-bar in my android application, it contains a text-field and a button. Now, if the user press enter in text field it goes to next line, I want to set a action for enter like if the user press the enter search button works, how to do this? is it possible in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is controlled by setting the `imeOptions` for that `TextView` ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)).  Setting it to a value like `actionGo` or `actionSearch` will change the return key's display and also keep it from adding a new line.

In order to react to the enter key event, you also need to attach an `OnEditorActionListener` ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)) via `setOnEditorActionListener()`, within which you place the code to do your search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
searchEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    switch (keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                            //Do whatever u want
                            return true;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: this works just for pc keyboard on emulator not for android keyboard